# Large update in Sybase

Tags: sybase, updates, long-integer

I need your help to solve a problem that I have with a large update. Hi we want to create a server for developers/testers and we want that have a copy from production, so we want to obfuscate the NSS with a random NSS generated at the moment that I execute the update, so I create a function that do this process. This its the update:

```
UPDATE CUSTOMERS SET 
NAME = 'John',
LAST NAME ='Doe',
NSS = RandomNSS    
plan '(i_scan PK_CUSTOMERS CUSTOMERS)'
```

The update works fine except that the table its 9 million long so I got the log suspended or the message that you are out of locks so the process never finish so I tried to implement the following:

```
SET ROWCOUNT  10000 

WHILE (1 = 1) 
  BEGIN 
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
UPDATE CUSTOMERS SET
NAME = 'John',
LAST NAME ='Doe',
NSS = RandomNSS    
plan '(i_scan PK_CUSTOMERS CUSTOMERS)'

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
      BEGIN 
        COMMIT TRANSACTION        
        BREAK 
      END     
    COMMIT TRANSACTION 
  END 

SET ROWCOUNT  0
```

But it doesn't solve the problem because I don't have a where clause so the update never finish even that all the customers name are John Doe, so can you help me to create a query that help me to finish this process?

Comment: Are the Production and Developement DB's on the same Sybase instance, or on different Sybase instances?

Comment: Are in different instances

Answer (score 0):

First, on the DEV system, I would change the setting for the databse so that it will truncate the transaction log when it checkpoints.  That will keep the log from filling up while you accomplish the update.  Because the DEV database is restored from PROD database, it's not important to dump the transaction logs for recoverability.

```
sp_dboption DEV_DB, 'trunc log on chkpt', true
```

If you must do the update, try changing the while loop to continue until all the names are changed to "John", like the following.

```
SET ROWCOUNT 10000

while ( select count(*) from CUSTOMERS where name != "John" and LAST_NAME != 'Doe' ) > 0
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRANSACTION
   UPDATE CUSTOMERS SET
     NAME = 'John',
     LAST NAME ='Doe',
     NSS = RandomNSS
   WHERE name != "John" AND LAST_NAME != "DOE"    
     plan '(i_scan PK_CUSTOMERS CUSTOMERS)'
   COMMIT TRANSACTION 
END 

SET ROWCOUNT  0
```

Alternatively, you can create a view on the database, grabbing the Production data you want, while obscuring the fields you don't want the devs to see.  This view can then be used to **select into** the DevelopementDB, or exported/imported with **bcp**

```
create view DEV_VIEW (NAME, LAST_NAME, NSS, colA, colB) as
select "John", "Doe", RandomNSS, other_colA, other_colB
from CUSTOMERS
```

Comment: I cant do this because the production server its being replicated to other location so the select into instruction is not available

Comment: Well what I did is restoring a back up for the production server, and In the future I will schedule the back up in the production server and then in the developers server and when it finish obfuscate some table but this table have been a problem

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your inner IF statement was accomplishing, but the code above should work, and keep the transaction log from filling up.

Comment: I beleive its because the size of the table, but with your comment I was thinking that I will update with thename "Jhon1" and in the where clause check if right!= 1 then do the update so I can control the ammount the update and the where clause will have an end